# C#: Regex for name with 2 and/or 3 words

Tags: c#, regex

In my C# app, user enters a name. I want to set a Regex where user can enter only 2 or 3 words i.e. "John Brandy" or "John Brandy Paul". And each word not less than 2 and greater than 15 chars.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(str, @"^[A-Z]+ [A-Z]+ [A-Z]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // @"^\b[a-zA-Z]{2,15}\s[a-zA-Z]{2,15}\b");  //@"(\w)\s(\w){2, 3}");
Console.WriteLine("PAttern Success = " + match.Success);
```

With the current pattern, I got to enter 3 words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another idea to use a [quantified](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx) [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```
^(?:[A-Z]{2,15} ?\b){2,3}$
```

- use with your `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`
- the `\b` stands for *[word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)*.

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VUvKon/4)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly. The link you shared is a great help to try patterns online & see the results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `?` to match zero and once, along with the pattern in your comment.

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2,15}\s[a-zA-Z]{2,15}(?:\s[a-zA-Z]{2,15})?$
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yKMl3A/1)

Additionally the `?:` tells that it should be a non-capturing group.

Note that `\s` also matches newlines, so you might instead want `[ \t]`. If you want to allow multiple spaces then use `[ \t]+`.

Answer (score 1):

try this it should work.

`^[a-zA-Z]{2,15}\s([a-zA-Z]{2,15}\s)?[a-zA-Z]{2,15}$`

Comment: this allows names of 1 character and greater than 15 characters (one the requirements OP specified)

Comment: sorry didn't notice that part of the requirement, easy enough, instead of the plus after the alpha class put {2,15}

Answer (score 0):

`^(?:[A-Z][A-Za-z]{2,15} ?\b){2,3}$` will work without using IgnoreCase